# Javascript sort date as string from array of objects without date object

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

If I have an array of objects, like:

```
[
{name: "First", updated: "2022-10-09"},
{name: "Second", updated: "null"},
{name: "Third", updated: "2022-12-06"}
]
```

Is there a way to sort in descending order by date without having to resort to creating date objects? And is there a way for it to filter out null values as well. I am not sure if the date as a string here qualifies as an ISO date and is readable as such - can it still be filtered as an ISO date?

So the final result would be:

```
[
{name: "Third", updated: "2022-12-06"}
{name: "First", updated: "2022-10-09"},
]
```

Comment: Date strings in that format can be sorted lexicographically.

Comment: So you can use `String.prototype.localeCompare()` as the comparison function.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but `array.sort()` sorts lexicographically by default

Comment: @pilchard I'd looked at that before, but it doesn't work. I wonder if it's because some of my "updated" can be null values?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski I can't seem to get it to sort, it just returns the original array

Comment: Sorts fine: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k48wb5rz/), but if you have `null` values you'll need to account for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just compare the string values like this:

```js
const arr = [
{name: "First", updated: "2022-10-09"},
{name: "Second", updated: "2021-11-14"},
{name: "Third", updated: "2022-12-06"}
]
console.log(arr.sort((a, b) => a.updated > b.updated ? -1 : 1))
```